# What is wrong with my Conditional Formatting Formula?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I want to change the text color to Red for cells in range A3:A25 by comparing the corresponding values in the worksheet named 'Stock Master'. i.e., if the corresponding value (reference present in Column A of 'Stock Master') in Column L of 'Stock Master' is less than the value in Column M of 'Stock Master', change the text color to RED.

I used the following custom formula for conditional and I am getting the Error Message: "Invalid Formula"

```
=vlookup(A3,INDIRECT('Stock Master'!$A$3:$M$300,12, False))<vlookup(A3, INDIRECT('Stock Master'!$A$3:$M$300,13,False))
```

What is wrong with my custom formula for conditional formatting?

Comment: Maybe your locale expects semicolons instead of commas?

Comment: Couldn't understand "locale" !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Syntax Error

[INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) takes a **reference-as-string** or a reference to a cell that contains a reference-as-string, but you are passing it a range reference.

You need to add quotation marks to convert the range reference to a reference-as-string.

#### Examples

1. Reference-as-string:

   - `"A:B"`
   - `"A1"`
2. Reference:

   - `A:B` - incorrect
   - `A1` - correct *only* if `A1` contains a reference-as-string.

#### Corrected Formula

```
=VLOOKUP(A3, INDIRECT("'Stock Master'!A3:M300"), 12, 0)<
 VLOOKUP(A3, INDIRECT("'Stock Master'!A3:M300"), 13, 0)
```

or using LET

```
=LET(r,INDIRECT("'Stock Master'!A3:M300"),
   VLOOKUP(A3, r, 12, 0)<VLOOKUP(A3, r, 13, 0))
```

#### Code Efficiency

- I replaced `FALSE` with `0`.
- I removed the absolute symbols `$` since they are meaningless in a text string.

#### Alternatives

```
=LEN(QUERY(
   INDIRECT("'Stock Master'!A3:M300"), 
   "WHERE Col1='"& A3 &"' AND Col12 < Col13"))
```

[image: Alternative formula 1]

```
=LET(r,INDIRECT("'Stock Master'!A3:M300"),
   SUMPRODUCT(A3=INDEX(r,,1),
     INDEX(r,,12)<INDEX(r,,13)))
```

[image: Alternative formula 2]

---

#### Functions Used

[INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)  [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)  [LET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535?hl=en)  [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)  [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294?hl=en)  [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)